# Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I don’t know why I’m getting this error. Can someone please help me.
I’ve declared variables as

```
jdetails: Array<any>;
cards: Array<any>;
```

This is my method

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FeedsPage');
    //for new card
    this.addnewcard();
    console.log(this.cards);
  }
addnewcard() {
    this.jobdetail.getJobDetails().then((data) => {
      //console.log(data);
      this.jdetails = data;
    });
    for (let val of this.jdetails) {
      this.cards.push(val);
    }
  }
```

When I press button,“voteUp” method get invoked

```
voteUp() {
    let removedcard = this.cards.pop();
    this.addnewcard();
  }
```

I’m facing type error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined at
>   FeedsPage.webpackJsonp.260.FeedsPage.addnewcard (feeds.ts:171) at
>   FeedsPage.webpackJsonp.260.FeedsPage.ionViewDidLoad (feeds.ts:63) at
>   ViewController._lifecycle (view-controller.js:486) at
>   ViewController._didLoad (view-controller.js:369) at
>   NavControllerBase._didLoad (nav-controller-base.js:768) at t.invoke
>   (polyfills.js:3) at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749) at t.invoke
>   (polyfills.js:3) at r.run (polyfills.js:3) at NgZone.run
>   (core.js:4566)

Comment: Initialise cards as an empty array `cards: Array<any> = []`

Answer (score 2):

Note: the error `Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined` usually occurs when there is an explicit call to `arr.length`, which I can't see in your example. I can see a couple of cases where I'd expect to see a `this.cards is undefined`.

You are looping over the `this.jdetails` member before it has been set (`.then` indicates asynchronous execution):

```
this.jobdetail.getJobDetails().then((data) => {
  //console.log(data);
  this.jdetails = data;
});
for (let val of this.jdetails) {
  this.cards.push(val);
}
```

Perform the processing of the data *after* it has been retrieved, by moving the loop into the `.then` function.

```
this.jobdetail.getJobDetails().then((data) => {
  //console.log(data);
  this.jdetails = data;

  for (let val of this.jdetails) {
    this.cards.push(val);
  }
});
```

I can't see all of your code as you haven't supplied a self-contained example, but there is an assumption when you call `push` or `pop` that the array has been initialized. If you don't do this, you'll probably have another error on your hands. Initialize it either inline or in your constructor:

```
cards: any[] = [];
```